# How to make a dashboard with ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, devexpress, dashboard

I am try to make a dashboard, I have google a soiution,but it need to pay money  [enter link description here](https://docs.devexpress.com/Dashboard/119284/get-started/build-web-dashboard-applications/create-an-aspnet-core-dashboard-application).

Can someone teach me other way to do?

Comment: What do you want `Other way to arrange money?` or `Dashboard?`

Comment: To Md Farid Uddin Kiron
:I mean make a dashboard without DevExpress package.

Comment: Its a long questions to answer, please split your question to a specific problem so that contributor can answer.

Comment: To Md Farid Uddin Kiron : Sorry, I am unfamiliar with this. Can you please tell me how to  split my question to a   specific problem.

Comment: Which feature you want to develop on dashborad? What did you tried so far?

Comment: To Md Farid Uddin Kiron : I will create a database, and dashboard can read the database , show the data status ， and it may be use SignalR to refresh page, I think most important problem is which tool can I use for make a dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the free version of the dashboard, you can use Grafana. It has a free version and a paid version. The effects are as follows:

[image]

Official website address:

https://grafana.com/grafana/

Implementation steps ：

[document:https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/?pg=docs](http://document:https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/?pg=docs)